# Pressed Listener for a View

Tags: android

In android, is there such a thing for listening if a View is pressed?
In background drawable, i can set assert depends on the view is pressed or not.

Is it possible for me to add a Listener for a View when I pressed it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set and OnClickListener to any View, which is the base class for just about everything in Android!

Comment: OnClick happens after pressing and releasing within the view, the question was just about pressing.

Comment: In that case, you can add a TouchListener and listen for the down event.

Comment: Unfortunately motion.getAction only shows MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN/MOVE/UP which doesn't quite act like the default pressed state does when you move outside the button area.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the Button class is for. It doesn't have to "look" like a button to be one.